# Terraform: getting project id from azuredevops_project resource. Error data.azuredevops_projects.projectname.projects is set of object with 1 element

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to access azuredevops project from terraform using azuredevops_devops resource. Using that project, I want to access repositories and create a new repo. But I am getting error in the second data block where I try to assign to project_id, but the output block prints the correct details.

```
data "azuredevops_projects" "sampleproject"{
    name = "sample"
}
output  "projectdetails"{
    value = [for obj in data.azuredevops_projects.sampleproject.projects : obj.name]
}
```

error I receive here is: Incorrect attribute value type.data.azuredevops_projects.sampleproject.projects is set of object with 1 element  :

```
data "azuredevops_git_repository" "samplerepo"{
    project_id = [for obj in data.azuredevops_projects.sampleproject.projects : obj.name]
    name = "Services-Template"
}
```

I am new to terraform, just practicing this for learning purpose.

Comment: Is your objective here to manage multiple `azuredevops_git_repository` each mapped to one of a `azuredevops_projects`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I tried everything but the below solution worked
initial outcome:

```
+ projectdetails = [
      + "74899dhjhjk-8909-4a97-9e9b-73488hfjikjd9",
    ]
```

outcoume after below solution:

```
element(data.azuredevops_projects.sampleproject.projects.*.project_id,0)
```

"74899dhjhjk-8909-4a97-9e9b-73488hfjikjd9"